# How to check that selected regex from char set in two sections are equal?

Tags: python, regex

**Test String:**`gcaaaattatacccacatttctttttaaaatttcagcaaaattttaaactatacg`

**What I want to detect:** any combination of two characters including "a" in them and the "a" cannot be the first character.

**Example:** gcaaaa`ttata` `cccaca` tttc `tttttaaaattt` cagcaaaattttaaac `tata` cg

**My Regex:** `[{g,t,c}]{2,}a[{a,g,t,c}]`

**Problem:** When it matches a character from the first set {g,t,c} it will match any character from the second list.

**My Question:** How to match from the second list what is already selected from the first set for an output like the example above.

---

> Update

**Further explanation**: 
 - The combination is of two characters only including "a"
 - "a" must be in between and cannot be the start. So , "ttttaaa" starting with t but nothing intercept the "a"s, if it was the same character "t" so match the pattern, If any character not "a" or "t" stop matching.

- **So these are working:** "tttaaat","tattttatatat"
- **These are not working:** "taaaaaaa","attttta"

*I'm writing in python if that could help.*

Comment: how does `tata` match your pattern?

Comment: 1- "a" is not the first character
2- all the combination is of two characters only including "a"

Comment: what about `ttttaaa` before that? or `caaaa` before that one?

Comment: "a" must be in between and cannot be the start.
So , "ttttaaa" starting with t but nothing intercept the "a"s, if it was the same character "t" so match the pattern, If any character not "a" or "t" stop matching.

Comment: I've posted an update, Please check it

Comment: ```\1``` references group one of the previous match. It is explained in the \number section of the re docs. There are numerous Python flavored online regex testers that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following:

```
import re

s = 'gcaaaattatacccacatttctttttaaaatttcagcaaaattttaaactatacg'
for match in re.finditer(r'(g|c|t)\1*a+(\1)(\1|a)*', s):
    print(match.group())
```

Output:

```
ttata
cccaca
tttttaaaattt
tata
```

Example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Pl5evJ/2). `(g|c|t)` matches any of the characters `gct` and captures it. `\1*a+\1` repeats the first character 0 or more times followed by at least one `a` followed by first character. `(\1|a)*` at the end then allows any combination of `a` and first character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `([gtc])\1*(a+)(\1+\2*)+` which will look for at least one g, t, or c followed by one or more a and then any combination of those two characters

```
import re

word='gcaaaattatacccacatttctttttaaaatttcagcaaaattttaaactatacg'

matches = re.finditer(r'([gtc])\1*(a+)(\1+\2*)+', word)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
  print(match.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to accomplish your goal would be to capture the first character and backreference it in the third portion of your expression.

like so:

```
(?P<first>[gtc])(?P=first)?a(?:a|(?P=first))*
```

[python regex reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)